# How to invalidate a Memcached value when updating a product's price in my custom PrestaShop 1.7 module?

Tags: php, prestashop, memcached, prestashop-1.7

I'm using a Prestashop 1.7 multistore. One of the stores has VAT enabled, while the other does not. I've created a custom module that hooks into the `updateproduct` hook. In this module, I update the price of a product, but only for the store without VAT. This ensures that both stores have the same final prices.

To enhance performance, I utilize Memcached. But I struggle to invalidate the cache correctly. Once the value for the non-VAT store gets cached (the one I alter in my module), it's never changed after attempting to set it again in the product admin. It changes properly in database, but Memcached retrieves the old value. How can I invalidate or update the stored value in Memcached? I have also no clue how to get the correct Memcached key as it's a hash like for example ps_288e7d9f7adabca7ca488166fced130a.

Currently, the only method I've found to refresh Memcached is to invalidate the entire cache, which seems to be a suboptimal solution in terms of performance.

```
Cache::getInstance()->delete('*');
```

This is my simplified hook function to update the price:

```
private function updateProductPrice($params)
    {
        $id_product = $params['id_product'];
        $price = $params['product']->price;
        $id_tax_rules_group = $params['product']->id_tax_rules_group;

        $shop_ids = $this->getShopIds();

        $tax_rate = $this->getTaxRate($id_tax_rules_group);

        foreach ($shop_ids as $shop_id) {
            $is_tax = Configuration::get('PS_TAX', null, null, $shop_id);
            $sql = 'SELECT `price`
                FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product`
                WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int) $id_product;
            $base_price = (float)Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
            
            if (!$is_tax) {
                $new_price = $base_price * (100 + $tax_rate) / 100;
                Db::getInstance()->update('product_shop', ['price' => $new_price], 'id_product = '.(int)$id_product . ' AND id_shop = '.(int)$shop_id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Without the Memcached enabled everything works just fine.

Comment: Memcached is a key/value storage. What do you want to invalidate? Just replace the key and use a short expiration time. https://www.php.net/manual/de/memcached.set.php. To delete all the keys, you need to use flush.

Comment: I'm using the Prestashop's CacheMemcached core class. I'm not working with Memcached directly. The delete method is actually calling flush. Also I don't know the Memcached key as it is handled by Prestashop.

Answer (score 0):

Object models have a `clearCache()` method that you could use on the product.

After calling the update query use the following code

```php
$params['product']->clearCache();
```

**As commented by the OP the above wont work as it clears only PHP cache.**

Although the proper way would be to set the price on the product object and call its `save()` method. Directly modifying the database skips all hooks that trigger before and after save and as per your issue it skips cache invalidation as well.

**The above also will not work as the OP is updating the product inside update product hook.**

After some digging through the core it seems that the cache keys are computed from the sql queries, so you can first build the price query as in the Product object.

Build frontend price query:

```php
$sql = new DbQuery();
$sql->select('product_shop.`price`, product_shop.`ecotax`');
$sql->from('product', 'p');
$sql->innerJoin('product_shop', 'product_shop', '(product_shop.id_product=p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = ' . (int) $id_shop . ')');
$sql->where('p.`id_product` = ' . (int) $id_product);
if (Combination::isFeatureActive()) {
    $sql->select('IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute,0) id_product_attribute, product_attribute_shop.`price` AS attribute_price, product_attribute_shop.default_on, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax` AS attribute_ecotax');
    $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute_shop', 'product_attribute_shop', '(product_attribute_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = ' . (int) $id_shop . ')');
} else {
    $sql->select('0 as id_product_attribute');
}
$sql = $sql->build();
```

Build admin product query:

```
$entity_defs = ObjectModel::getDefinition(Product::class);
$sql = new DbQuery();
$sql->from($entity_defs['table'], 'a');
$sql->where('a.`' . bqSQL($entity_defs['primary']) . '` = ' . (int) $id);

// Get lang informations
if ($id_lang && isset($entity_defs['multilang']) && $entity_defs['multilang']) {
    $sql->leftJoin($entity_defs['table'] . '_lang', 'b', 'a.`' . bqSQL($entity_defs['primary']) . '` = b.`' . bqSQL($entity_defs['primary']) . '` AND b.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang);
    if ($id_shop && !empty($entity_defs['multilang_shop'])) {
        $sql->where('b.`id_shop` = ' . (int) $id_shop);
    }
}

// Get shop informations
if (Shop::isTableAssociated($entity_defs['table'])) {
    $sql->leftJoin($entity_defs['table'] . '_shop', 'c', 'a.`' . bqSQL($entity_defs['primary']) . '` = c.`' . bqSQL($entity_defs['primary']) . '` AND c.`id_shop` = ' . (int) $id_shop);
}
$adminSql = $sql->build();
```

Compute the cache keys from queries.

```php
$keyFrontend = Cache::getInstance()->getQueryHash($sql);
$keyAdmin = Cache::getInstance()->getQueryHash($adminSql);
```

Delete the keys.

```php
Cache::getInstance()->delete($keyFrontend);
Cache::getInstance()->delete($keyAdmin);
```

You should do some checks first if the caching is active so the code works with and without cache.

Although all this is/feels hackish and I don't know how this affects any other price calculations such as specific prices, discounts etc. as their sql queries might also need cache invalidation. I have tried to find out how the admin page invalidates product cache on save to find an easier way but had no luck so far in figuring that out.

Comment: The ```clearCache()``` method works only with the local PHP cache and not with Memcached. Also, I cannot use the ```save()``` method because I'm already within the ```updateproduct``` hook, which would create an infinite loop. Furthermore, I need to target the specific shop_id for the non-VAT shop in order to maintain the same prices in both VAT and non-VAT shops. This goes against the default PrestaShop behavior, which adds VAT to the base price. That's my reason for skipping the proper way.